# com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter: null org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException

Tags: mule, agent

```
Hello I am getting below exception when I tried to deploy some applications to mule enterprise ESB 3.5.2 and mmc 3.5.2. I could not get the exact reason? Please provide some input/suggestions.

Stacktrace is as follow:
```

Pinging the JVM took 16 seconds to respond.
    Pinging the JVM took 12 seconds to respond.
    Pinging the JVM took 8 seconds to respond.
    Pinging the JVM took 3 seconds to respond.
    ERROR 2014-11-18 11:06:58,815 [qtp1783168956-50] com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter: null org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:914)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.flush(AbstractGenerator.java:443)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$Output.flush(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1101)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1793)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:699)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.close(ObjectOutputStream.java:720)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.writeRemoteInvocationResult(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:176)
        at com.mulesoft.common.remoting.StreamSupportingHttpInvokerServiceExporter.writeRemoteInvocationResult(StreamSupportingHttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:116)
        at com.mulesoft.common.remoting.StreamSupportingHttpInvokerServiceExporter.writeRemoteInvocationResult(StreamSupportingHttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:74)
        at com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.remoting.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
        at com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter.doFilter(ConsoleClientCertFilter.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:358)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:346)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:781)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:753)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.writeTo(ByteArrayBuffer.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:838)
        ... 46 more
    WARN  2014-11-18 11:06:59,971 [qtp1783168956-50] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response: Committed before 500 Internal server error, please try again.
    WARN  2014-11-18 11:06:59,972 [qtp1783168956-50] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler: /mmc-support/api/v3/statusService
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:317)
        at com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter.doFilter(ConsoleClientCertFilter.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    ERROR 2014-11-18 11:07:08,704 [qtp1783168956-171] com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter: null
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:914)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.flush(AbstractGenerator.java:443)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$Output.flush(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1101)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1793)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:699)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.close(ObjectOutputStream.java:720)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.writeRemoteInvocationResult(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:176)
        at com.mulesoft.common.remoting.StreamSupportingHttpInvokerServiceExporter.writeRemoteInvocationResult(StreamSupportingHttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:116)
        at com.mulesoft.common.remoting.StreamSupportingHttpInvokerServiceExporter.writeRemoteInvocationResult(StreamSupportingHttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:74)
        at com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.remoting.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
        at com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter.doFilter(ConsoleClientCertFilter.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:358)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:346)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:781)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:753)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.writeTo(ByteArrayBuffer.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:838)
        ... 46 more
    WARN  2014-11-18 11:07:08,850 [qtp1783168956-171] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response: Committed before 500 Internal server error, please try again.
    WARN  2014-11-18 11:07:08,851 [qtp1783168956-171] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler: /mmc-support/api/v3/statusService
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:317)
        at com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter.doFilter(ConsoleClientCertFilter.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Pinging the JVM took 3 seconds to respond.

Comment: 5 years later, I'm having same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue, I put truststore.jks from mule.mule.agent to mmc-console\webapps\mmc\WEB-INF\classes.

Exception(com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.web.ConsoleClientCertFilter:null org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException) is no longer there but My Mule server in mmc is not going to OK status. it is in Failed status.

When I Removed truststore.jks from mmc-console\webapps\mmc\WEB-INF\classes I am getting above exception but My Mule Server is going to OK status.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is occurring only when I am debugging Mule application component classes.

When Mule is application is not debugged then the above issue never occurs